# Where is "click sortable" set for a field?

Tags: views, 9

I am trying to properly fix a bug in D8/9 core which removes the ability for link fields to be "click sortable" in a Views table.

I know I can do a views_data_alter hook to set the field as "click sortable" but I am guessing there is a schema or annotation change I can make to fix this? Anyone have any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and used hook_field_views_data_alter and created this patch for core: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3239705.